# Why I can't see 'kubelet' container on crictl ps results(containerd)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, crictl

I'm operating simple kubernetes cluster(CRI is containerd).
In the cluster, "crictl ps" command doesn't return "kubelet" container.

In another kubernetes cluster(CRI is docker), "docker ps" command returns "kubelet" container.

What is the difference between these two commands(docker ps / crictl ps)?

Is there any way to see "kubelet" container by "crictl ps" command?

Answer (score 1):

`crictl` isn't a replacement for `docker`. The result of `crictl ps` doesn't include some containers (e.g. `pause`).

Try `ctr -n k8s.io c ls` to see all the containers running on k8s with containerd.